# Flutter - Resize image and apply fit in dart language, contains example in nodejs javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, flutter, dart, image-processing

How do I convert an image to base64, resizing and applying the fit in the flutter language?

image example is in NodeJS

I already searched the internet and language documentation

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.